# How to get GeoServer WMS with base map as OpenStreet map?

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms

I am using the latest version of GeoServer (2.16.2). I am able to fetch the WMS of my layer using the following code,

```html
<img src="http://localhost/geoserver/tajikistan/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=country%3Ajamoat&bbox=353577.4375%2C4059412.5%2C1023945.625%2C4547171.0&width=768&height=558&srs=EPSG%3A32642&format=application/openlayers">
```

For now, the `img` tag producing the image without `osm layer`. I need to add `osm layer` as baselayer and display through `img` tag. The above code will produce the map like following,

[image]

But I want to display this map with `OSM base layer` like below map,
[image]

I know I can overlay it with osm in leaflet map view (not in `<img src=""> tag`), by using following code,

```js
//load admin layer data form geoserver
const mywms = L.tileLayer.betterWms(
  "http://localhost/geoserver/tajikistan/wms",
  {
    layers: "country:layer",
    format: "image/png",
    transparent: true,
    version: "1.1.0",
    attribution: "country layer"
  }
).addTo(map);
```

How can I add the osm base layer in my WMS URL?

Comment: what do you mean 'in WMS'? Leaflet will be using WMS (or WMTS) to produce the map.

Comment: I mean I want to insert the WMS layer as `img` or `png` format so that I can add it into `img src` tag.

Comment: please [edit] the question to make it clearer

Comment: I just edited my post. Please answer it where it is possible or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, you could create a single WMS image if (and only if) you have an OSM base layer in your WMS server. A WMS request can only request layers that are available on the server you make the request to.

The only (sort of) exception to this is if the server you are using is cascading a layer from another server but since OSM is not generally served using OGC standards it is unlikely that you will be able to do this on your server.

You could use [GeoSolutions pre-prepared OSM data directory](https://www.geosolutionsgroup.com/blog/geoserver-osm-styles-full-data-directory-available/) and then add your own data layer but it seems like a lot of work for this.

Comment: Ohh really! Thank you for the information. Do you know any baselayers that I can add in my map background using this `img` tag?

Comment: No, as I explained you can only add layers that are on your server!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can serve basemap such as storing Geopackage and applying style,

But you can also serve them via `Cascading WMTS`, if you don't want to host them locally. The link below will explain it in details.

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/cascaded/wmts.html

For example, if you want to use ESRI Basemaps

Add Capabilities url
https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/NatGeo_World_Map/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

by adding a new data source via New Data Source and then picking WMTS - Cascades a remote Web Map Tile Service ,

[image]

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).